# Google Maps advanced features in a MapActivity (Google Maps API)

Tags: android, api, android-intent, maps

I wanted to load a custom KML file on the map. I chose the simple way:

```
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
```

And it works well, but obviously I can't control various features like custom icons for overlay items, or the popup "Loading myKml.kml..." that shows everytime I start it, etc.

First question:
**Aren't there any parameters to setup when I start a Google Maps Intent, to tweak my map? I can't find anything on the documentation.**

So I was thinking about using the Google Maps API for my app. Well, I've managed to load my KML file parsing it with a SAX parser and creating a custom overlay for my map.

It works, but there is a great problem:
The placemarks aren't loaded dynamically in relation to my position. They are loaded from the start to the end, and are shown on the map 100 at time.

So it was going to be harder than I thought, because I'll have to get my position from the GPS and calculate only the nearest points and draw them on the map.

Second question:
**Does exist a built-in function to show only near-to-me placemarks on the map?**

Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 0):

2nd question. No. Have a look at `LocationManager.addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude, float radius, long expiration, PendingIntent intent)`.